# convert 5112225.14 to 5,112,225.14 in ios 6

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios6

How do I convert `5112225.14` to `5,112,225.14` in ios 6 . I tried this:

```
NSNumber *numberObj = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:[[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""] floatValue]];
```

also tried

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
[formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; // this line is important!

NSString *formatted = [formatter stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:2000000.879]];
```

But I get **5,112,225** for first and **2,000,000**  without any decimal .How do I retain even the decimal point and the comma separated value .Thanks in Advance and Merry Christmas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using NSNumberFormatter is the proper way. You are failing because you are calling `numberWithInteger` instead of `numberWithDouble`.

Comment: Thanks rmaddy Awesome answer but when I type **2000000.81234**     I get 2,000,000.812 only 3 digits and no comma.By the way does decimal place have comma in them I dont know for the above structure.Thanks.

Comment: How can you say you get 2,000,000.812 and no comma? I see two commas. If you want more decimal places then use the NSNumberFormatter methods for setting the number of decimal places you want. No commas should appear in the decimal part, just the integer part.

Comment: Oh Alright Thanks again rmaddy what NSNumberFormatter method do I use to retain 5 digits after the point.Thanks again.

Comment: A quick scan of the NSNumberFormatter reference docs will show you the method you need. But since it is Christmas I'll tell you myself :) You want setMaximumFractionDigits:

Comment: Thanks for the Christmas Gift.Have a great day.